# TypeError: ForeignKey.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'on_delete'

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I am trying to define a foreign_key in a model in Django. But I am getting the error **"TypeError: ForeignKey.**init**() got multiple values for argument 'on_delete'"**

The way I define the field is like this:

```
class School(BaseModel):
    student_number = models.ForeignKey(Student,_("student_number"), max_length=200,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I don't really see why I am getting this error, because I have exact same implementation in other classes, and they do not raise an error.

Comment: Please share entire error trace